# Thermocouple parallel reading

Tags: filter, low-pass, thermocouple

I need to read 5 thermocouple sensors from a plastic injection machine. I want to use a [MAX6675](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX6675.pdf) because it has a cold junction compensation feature.

I can achieve parallel readings with 2°C offset in office tests, but when I try the same readings with the injection machine, the temperature readings are unstable. For example, if the actual temperature is 230°C in the machine, I am reading between 190-260°C and the temperature value changes very fast.

For stabilizing the results I have tried an RC low-pass filter, but the temperature value rises to near 395°C in office tests. An op-amp buffer caused similar results. As a buffer op-amp I used an [OP07C](https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/op07c). Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Can we see a schematic of your office set up and your machine set up? Pictures of the two enviroments may also help. Where and how are you connecting the thermocouples to the PCB?

Comment: Possibly related: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/638203/four-max6675-give-different-temperature-values-at-room-temperature